# Can't understand why I can't access the value of counter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Why does the conditional statement inside `handleDecrement` `if(counter>1)` not work?

```
const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(1);

function handleIncrement (counter){
  setCounter(counter => counter + 1)
}
function handleDecrement (counter){
  if(counter>1){
    setCounter(counter => counter - 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions?

Comment: <Button onClick={handleIncrement}>
and
<Button onClick={handleDecrement}>

Comment: Both your functions will be passed an event object and not the counter. You can omit the `counter` in your functions' arguments to use the one in the surrounding scope obtained by useState()

Comment: Thanks! I removed "counter" from the arguments and now it works (even though I didn't get the why of it :/ )

Comment: The function that you pass to `onClick` will get passed an event object representing the event that occurred (assuming your `<Button />` component handles onClick events this way), it can have information about the click such as the element that was clicked etc. You never pass `counter` to your functions so you shouldn't expect them to receive it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling these function inside `setCounter`, you're just passing arrow function definitions and not the calculated value of the counter, so then inside the if statement, you're comparing not the integer with integer, but a function definition with an integer.

Fixed code:

```js
const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(1);

function handleIncrement(counterArg) {
  setCounter(counterArg + 1)
}

function handleDecrement(counterArg) {
  if (counterArg > 1) {
    setCounter(counterArg - 1)
  }
}
```

And then attaching it to onClick event:

```js
<Button onClick={() => handleIncrement(counter)}>
<Button onClick={() => handleDecrement(counter)}>
```